# Check number input and ask it until he enters a number

Tags: c

I want to check the user input if it is a number and I want the program to accept only a number as an input. I don't know if I explained myself clearly, I'll try by showing you an example:

```
int x;
printf("Write a number: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
while(!isdigit(x))
{
    printf("Not valid\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &x);
}
```

I tried using `scanf("%d", &x) != 1` as a while condition but it remains inside the loop. Is there a way to ask an input until the user writes a number? For now I just return the function but I'd like not to.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` now that's *bad*. Lookup why you should not flush `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the return value of `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    while (printf("Write a number: "),
           scanf("%d", &x) != 1)  // when the number of successful conversion wasn't 1
    {
        fputs("Not valid!\n", stderr);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');  // clear stdin from garbage
    }                                                   // that might be left.
}
```